# Enroll MCCGQ12LM (Aqara Door & Window Sensor T1)

Tags: wireshark, zigbee, home-automation

Has anyone successfully enrolled a MCCGQ12LM into a custom coordiantor? I would love to look at some logs, or get some guidelines.

I'm trying to enroll my MCCGQ12LM into my CIE, and after writing the CIE address to the CIE Address attribute, i get the ZoneEnrollRequest which i reply with a ZoneEnrollReponse. Everything seems to look correct on wireshark:

[Zone Enroll Request][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUwwe.png

[Zone Enroll Response][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jX5cR.png

But if i read the ZoneState attribute afterwards, it is still marked as Value: 0x00 [NotEnrolled].
The same process has been tested on a Samsung Multisensor, and works perfectly.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, you have to include a payload in the Zone Enroll Response, with the Enroll Response code, and the Zone ID.